# How to assign a Collection to an SSIS Task Property

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, expression

I have a "*Transfer SQL Server Object*" Task on an SSIS package and I want to store a Collection of tables in a package variable, and then assign this variable to the `ObjectsToCopy.TablesList` property of the task with an *Expression*.

Aparently this should work, I can create a variable and assign it to the task property through an expresion. My question is what is the proper variable type and syntax to save a collection of tables in a variable?

I've been testing but can't find the proper syntax (with a string variable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent a few hours on exactly the same problem a few days ago. As far as I can tell through extensive Googling, there is no way to assign a list of tables in a way that the task can understand. I ended up hardcoding the tables in the list provided in the task editor. Not ideal at all.

Failing that, there is the [roll your own task](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2007/04/18/roll-your-own-transfer-sql-server-objects-task.aspx) approach.

Comment: I got an approach to configure tables with an standard string and then parse this string to a collection (object variable) in a .net task. You should then assign this object variable to the property. It's interesting this roll your own task approach too. I'll try both ways to decide with one is more usefull and maintainable. Thanks!